# Multiple Redis instances with shared memory

Tags: kubernetes, redis, redis-cluster

In our project, we want to increase the performance of caching, actually we use a single Redis instance called by multiple microservices. Sometimes the instance is down.
Is there a way to have multiple Redis instances with shared memory managed by Kubernetes ?
Thank you

Comment: Not exactly using `shared memory` but you should take a look at [redis replication](https://redis.io/docs/manual/replication/)

Comment: with replicas, the data is deplicated asynchronously, in our case the app demands a high level of consistency if we want to use replicas

Comment: Check out Redis Raft if you need consistency https://github.com/RedisLabs/redisraft

Answer (score 1):

you can create redis cluster with at least 3 instanses

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/09/redis-clustering.html#InstallingRedis

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).